# Concatenate ntext in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ntext

I need to concatenate 2 ntext columns into one. I can't convert them to nchar, cause both contains strings longer than 4000 chars.
Is there a way to do this in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
    YourTable
SET 
    Field = CAST( (CAST(field1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(field2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS NTEXT)
WHERE 
    (your condition here)
```

But really - with SQL Server 2005, `NTEXT` becomes deprecated and will most likely be phased out in SQL Server 2008 R2 or one release later. `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is the logical successor, giving you all `NTEXT` ever gave you, and a lot more!

If your fields would be `NVARCHAR(MAX)` from the beginning, you could just write:

```
UPDATE 
    YourTable
SET 
    field = field1 + field2
WHERE 
    (your condition here)
```

and be done with it!

I'd suggest you upgrade your tables to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `NTEXT`.

Marc

Comment: Hi Marc. 
I don't want to try to convert them because of risk of breaking the app: MS Team Foundation Server.
I have enough misery without 'fixing' it. 

Thanks for your solution. Worked like magic ;).

Comment: Hi @marc_s I think you might have a tiny little typo in your first example, "NEXT" rather than "NTEXT". (Good answer though, +1 from me)

Comment: @AlexKey: yes, absolutely right! Thanks for catching that - updated my response

Comment: Hi Marc_s, If i have field1 as ntext and content is >4000 char. The command CAST(field1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) will auto TRIM field1. It not work

Answer (score 3):

Convert them to `nvarchar(max)` for the concatentation. It's the SQL 2005 replacement for `ntext` and allows all the usual `nvarchar` operations.

Comment: Can't convert them because of risk of breaking the app: MS TFS. I'm just trying to hack some fields.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to update ntext column:

```
DECLARE @memo binary(16)

SELECT 
    @memo = TEXTPTR(field1)
FROM 
    YourTable
WHERE 
    (your condition here)

UPDATETEXT YourTable.field1 @memo NULL 0 'Text to append'
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx) are more information.