# Problems with the add operator when creating a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

See my code below along with error message.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SubscriptionDescriptionNotes

ON [dbo].[Subscriptions]

AFTER INSERT, UPDATE

AS

UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions

SET [Description] = -- parse Parameter column and add to Description

                             [Parameters]  + Description

FROM [dbo].[Subscriptions] s

  WHERE s.[Parameters] LIKE '' --again parse parameter with condition what you want
```

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SubscriptionDescriptionNotes, Line 13
>   The data types ntext and nvarchar are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: The datatypes of text and ntext have been deprecated since sql 2005. They are a serious pain to work with. You should move to (n)varchar(max) instead. Do you REALLY need to use max? Those datatypes can hold a LOT of data. I also, don't see you using the inserted or deleted virtual tables in here. As posted this will update the entire Subscriptions table every time this trigger fires.

Comment: I agree with what Sean says, especially about updating the entire table.  Your core logic is wrong.  Beyond that, the problem you're facing is that [ntext doesn't support concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272416/concatenate-ntext-in-sql-server-2005).  As it is you'll have to do something like `SET [Description] = CAST([Parameters] AS nvarchar(max))  + Description` or `SET [Description] = CAST([Parameters] + CAST(Description as nvarchar(max)) as ntext)` depending on which field is ntext.